# Multiply two numbers together (by repeated addition) in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I have written a basic program to multiply two positive numbers, as follows:

```
# multiply two numbers together via addition
.globl main

main:
    # Lets put the two numbers into two registers
    # You must use `movl` or the `l` suffix when moving something into the %eax register
    movl    $7,       %ebx
    movl    $8,       %ecx
    # Zero out another register where we can do the additions
    # We will zero out eax because that is what linux expects as return
    movl    $0,       %eax

add_step:
    # Add the data from the first number (ebx) into the eax register ecx times
    addl    %ebx,    %eax
    # Decrement the second number (ecx), assuming it is positive
    dec     %ecx
    jnz     add_step
    # Shouldn't the 'return' statement occur in `main` and not in this subroutine?
    ret
```

Does this approach seem more-or-less valid? Are numbers usually pushed into a register to work with or are those usually offset from some base value or so? Finally, where should the `ret` go? It seems like the program flow should be something like:

```
main
    some_stuff()
    add_step()
    some_stuff()
    return
```

But I'm not really sure how to do that with the labels and all. What would be the suggested way to do this?

Comment: `add_step` isn't a subroutine, it's a label within `main`.  Think of it like a `goto` label in C.  It's being jumped to, not called.

Comment: Labels aren't functions if you're not using `call` to jump to them, they're just like the top of a `do{}while()` loop.  Yes, use registers not memory when you can.  This code looks correct (but would be more interesting with values that weren't assemble-time constants).  Except that you destroy EBX/RBX for main's caller.  RBX is call-preserved in normal calling conventions; pick a different register like EDX.  (All mainstream x86 and x86-64 calling convention have call-clobbered EAX, ECX, and EDX).

Comment: Also, what platform are you compiling for?  With Unix-like systems, the ABI requires ebx to be preserved, so you should either push/pop it or choose another register without this requirement (edx would work).

Comment: @NateEldredge Is this what you mean? `Linux ip-1...5 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @NateEldredge could you please explain what you mean by `the ABI requires ebx to be preserved` ? What is ebx used for then.

Comment: @David542: The [System V ABI](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI) defines, among other things, the *calling conventions* used by compilers and library functions.  Since `main` is normally expected to be compiled by a C compiler, it must obey those conventions.  One is that `ebx, esi, edi, ebp, esp` must have the same values when your function returns as when it was called, so if you want to use those registers, you have to save and restore their values (normally by pushing to the stack).  The choice of these registers is basically arbitrary (except esp and to some extent ebp).

Comment: @David542: The flip side is that when you call a C or library function, you can keep data in those registers and expect it to still be there afterwards, whereas any data you had in eax, ecx, edx can be destroyed.